# Schema editor collection sampling is missing fields

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to use the ODBC Schema Editor to connect to several Cosmos DB collections for reporting purposes (using Power BI). While I can successfully generate a schema for one collection, another is not working correctly.

The Document in question includes a request object. Within request there should be multiple fields. When I sample my collection in Schema Editor, the resulting schema is missing any array of objects (or anything that includes an array of objects) that should be included under the request object – they are just not listed in the resulting schema. Several others are properly split out into their own tables, but the tables are always empty when the schema is applied (this is not reflective of the underlying data – I would expect to see things in those tables). Behavior does not change if the same collection is re-sampled.

Here's an example:
[JSON selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bDWF.png)

Does anyone know how I can get the schema editor to recognize all of my data? I'm not sure what to share that would be helpful but I'm happy to provide more if there's something that would be informative.

EDIT: Unless I'm misunderstanding how to query Cosmos DB, it seems that I'm seeing the issue show up even if I try to query the data directly through Data Explorer. In the below, you can see if I select c.request.preparedBy that preparedBy has a property mail:

[preparedBy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI0sR.png)

However, if I try to query c.request.preparedBy.mail directly then I see nothing but blanks, which is exactly what appeared in the Schema Editor:

[preparedBy.mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I67Ex.png)

Thinking that maybe there was a limit to how many layers of depth I could query, I tried selecting from request instead of the entire collection. Interestingly, even though I see preparedBy when I select * from request, request.preparedBy again returns nothing but empty braces.

Comment: Which Cosmos DB Service API are you using? Note: Connecting to Azure Cosmos DB with the ODBC driver is currently supported for Azure Cosmos DB SQL API accounts only.

Comment: Also, which sampling method did you set up: Collection Mapping or Table-Delimiters? I think you want to use collection mapping method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/odbc-driver#a-idcollection-mappingastep-3-create-a-schema-definition-using-the-collection-mapping-method

Comment: Hi Mike, I never heard back from the AskCosmosDB email account :( I am using the SQL API account with Collection Mapping

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT I wasn't sure if you saw that I answered your questions?

Comment: By Cosmos group not responding I am assuming they found no issues with the service. So, in the Json that is missing, is it missing in the PowerBI Data Model or is it missing in the queries used to populate the data model? Can you query for the data (through data explorer)? Let ask around....

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT that's a great question. It appears to me that I still see this same behavior when querying directly in Data Explorer, through it's possible I've misunderstood the Cosmos DB query documentation. I've edited my initial question above to show an example of the data not appearing.

Comment: So, for the missing Json, should this come from a nested properties for a given document or from a separate collection? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#SelectClause

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT it's all nested.

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT any updates?

Comment: Do you have an Azure support plan? If not, please send your subscription GUID to AzCommunity at Microsoft.com and I can have a one time ticket created to investigate this issue given that you are not receiving any support from the community. With a support ticket created, we have more access to your environment and can separate product functionality versus data issues. Thank you.